# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' - hmac

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64, hmac

I see this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' 
    python3.6/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)`
```

Here is the code:

```
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii

....
def post(self,request):
    body = str(request.body).encode()
    sign_signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new('tester'.encode(), body, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace that line of your code with this:

```
sign_signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new('tester'.encode(), body, hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

> `digest` returns `bytes` -> we want to b64encode it, and b64encode accepts bytes, so we're good.